# How to decompose $\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{(1-x)}}$ into partial fractions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, problem-solving, partial-fractions

Basically homework help. The question (*Problems of Calculus in One Variable*, IA Maron, number **2.3.9(b)**) is to find the derivative of the 100th order of the function
$$
y = \frac{1+x}{\sqrt{(1-x)}}
$$
by 'expansion into a linear combination of simpler functions'.

I can't find any help online. There is a hint at the back, which says that $y$ can be written as $2(\sqrt{1-x})^{-1} - \sqrt{1-x}$, but how we get that, I have no idea.

How am I supposed to decompose $y$?

Comment: Did you try anything to see if that is true?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja I did take the LCM to see, ofc, and it checked out. But that still sheds no light on how we get to the decomposed $y$.

Comment: You could try a linear substitution. Let $u = 1 - x$, and see what happens when you fully expand out the expression in terms of $u$.

Comment: **Hint:** $x+1=x-1+2$. Rewrite the numerator like this and you can rewrite the fraction, simplifying in the indicated way.

Comment: @Clayton But what is the motivation to do so (as in, why would I wish to do that on seeing the problem)?

Comment: @TheoBendit again, what should be the reason that I do this? Can this be taken as a standard approach in some case?

Comment: Not that this means much, but the decomposition would not leap out at me. If you let $z=\sqrt{1-x}$, then $z^2 = 1-x$ and the above is ${2-z^2 \over z}$ which gives the decompostition.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for clarifying that this is not a standard method (but a cleverer one!)

Comment: @Aadi Intuition, primarily. If I were to see this in an integral, this would be the first thing I try. Why? Because I've seen similar things before. I know that, if a linear expression appears in a square root, but otherwise there are just polynomial terms, it is often helpful to turn the square root into a $\sqrt{u}$. From there, it might take some partial fractions, or some rationalising the denominator, but you should be able to resolve it as a sum of powers of $u$.

Comment: In response to Aadi’s question: I don’t like fractions. If I can manipulate the numerator to reduce a fraction, then my first step will be to follow through on this and hope it leads somewhere. In this case, the denominator had $(x-1)^{1/2}$, so I “made” an $x-1$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  Rewrite the numerator:   $1+x = 2 - (1 - x)$. Thus $f(x)=\dfrac{1+x}{\sqrt{1-x}}= \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{1-x}} - \sqrt{1-x} = 2(1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - (1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. From this you can find the first few derivatives and see an inductive pattern that leads to a formula for the $f^{(100)}(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$y=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^{1/2}}$,

$y’=\frac{(3-x)}{2(1-x)^{3/2}}$,

$y’’=\frac{(7-x)}{2^{2}(1-x)^{5/2}}$,

$y’’’=\frac{3(11-x)}{2^{3}(1-x)^{7/2}}$,

$y’’’’=\frac{3.5(15-x)}{ 2^{4}(1-x)^{9/2}}$,

…      …      …     …    …

$y^{(n)}=\frac{(4n-1-x).\prod_{k=2}^n\left(2k-3\right)}{2^{n}(1-x)^{\frac{2n+1}{2}}}$.

Just substitute for n, 100 and you're done.